# Electron Require Returns Undefined with any module

Tags: javascript, electron, desktop-application

I'm trying to build an electron app for the first time. I want it to open and save files, and I'm trying to use the dialog module for that. Whenever I run
`const dialog = require('electron');` or  do the same with the remote module, the assigned constant is always undefined for that one particular file I am using for my scripts. On my main.js, I use the same require statement and it works like a charm. However, on my scripts file which is called render.js, it doesn't work.

I don't really know where the problem is, so I'm also providing my package.json

```
  "name": "first-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^11.0.2"
  }
}
```

main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, screen, dialog, Menu } = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  const { width, height } = screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize
  console.log(width)
  console.log(height)
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: width,
    height: height,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
  win.loadFile('index.html');

  win.maximize()
  
  const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([{label: 'File'}]);

  Menu.setApplicationMenu(MainMenu);
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Comment: did you perhaps disable (or not enable) `nodeIntegration` in the window in which you load your renderer? We'd need to see your main.js/renderer code to diagnose this

Comment: @pushkin I did have `nodeIntegration` enabled in my main.js. Do I need to enable it in my scripts? If so, how?

Comment: oh, you'll want to also set `enableRemoteModule: true` and use the remote module from the renderer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ElectronJS: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "BrowserWindow" / "getCurrentWindow" of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64971120/electronjs-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-browserwindow-getcurre)